# Pandas Group by and create new column with 25th and 75th percentiles

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'id': [1, 1, 1, 2],
                   'r': [1000, 1300, 1400, 1100],
                   's': [650, 720, 565, 600]
                 })
```

I'd like to aggregate the DataFrame and create a new column which is a range of `r` values - `25th` and `75th` percentiles. The aggregate for `s` columns is `mean`.

If there is only one observation for a group, then keep the observations as it is.

Expected output:

```
id  r               s

1   1075 - 1325     645
2   1100            600
```

Comment: Why is 1100 on its own row?

Comment: @CodeDifferent because it is the only observations for `id` 2.

Comment: Which interpolation method do you want to use for the percentiles?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option, using [`Groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html), [`quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html), and a regex.

*NB. I am not fully sure which interpolation method you expect for the quantiles (check the linked documentation, there are several options).*

```
import re

out = (df
 .groupby('id')
 .agg({'r': lambda x: re.sub(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) - \1', r'\1',
                             x.quantile([0.25, 0.75])
                              .astype(str).str.cat(sep=' - ')),
      's': 'mean'})
 )
```

Output:

```
                  r      s
id                        
1   1150.0 - 1350.0  645.0
2            1100.0  600.0
```

Comment: what if I'd like to use other agg functions like `min` and `max`, instead of `quantiles`? Would prefer a solution without `regex` function.

Comment: Check the documentation of `agg`, it is quite powerful, you can use many aggregation functions (e.g `x.agg(['min', 'max'])`), even define your own. Why don't you want a regex?

Comment: just feel like it adds a bit of complexity. I am not good with `regex` and prefer to use a solution I fully understand. So, I'd just replace `x.quantile` with `x.agg(['min','max'])` ?

Comment: can you explain what the regex is doing?

Comment: It removes one of the bounds if the two bounds are identical. For this, if it matches.a number a dash and the same number, it replaces everything with the number only.

Comment: do you mind sharing a non-regex solution? I think there is too much going on in my pandas DataFrame for it to work. The code posted on SO is just a sample.

Answer (score 2):

Option two:

```
g_id = df.groupby('id')

g_id['r'].quantile([.25, .76])\
         .unstack()\
         .assign(s=g_id['s'].agg('mean'))
```

Output:

```
      0.25    0.76      s
id                       
1   1150.0  1352.0  645.0
2   1100.0  1100.0  600.0
```

Details:

Create a groupby object g_id, which we will use a twice.

g_id['r'].quantile([.25,.75]) returns a multiindex Series with out level as id, and the inner level as the label for percentile 25 and 5.  You can then unstack this inner level to create columns.  Lastly, we assign a new column to this dataframe with the g_id of S aggregated using mean.

Comment: what if I'd like to use other agg functions like `min` and `max`, instead of `quantiles`? Do you mind adding that to the answer?

Comment: could add a little explanation for what the 2nd line of code is doing?